# Editable Shiny DT with multiple checkboxes per row, and number of rows dependent on numericInput

Tags: r, shiny

The code in this question is based partially on the code from this question, and it's example can be used for reference:
[Add multiple checkboxes in shiny datatable and retrieve it's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76333449/add-multiple-checkboxes-in-shiny-datatable-and-retrieve-its-value)

So I have a numeric input to determine how many rows a Shiny DT will have. In that DT, I want to be able to edit two columns: one named `Phases` and another called `Duration`. Then, some mathematics will be done in the columns called `Start` and `End`. As well, I want checkboxes to be included in columns called `Linear Regression` and `Habituation`. The information for this DT, including booleans of whether the checkboxes are checked, are stored in `reactiveDF`.

I'm getting the error below, but I'm not sure which part of my code I need to make reactive in order to do what I am triyng to do.

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
```

I feel as though I might be fairly close, but I'm not 100% sure. Does anyone have any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

#This adds checkboxes for every row, as many rows are in the dataframe
checkboxColumn <- function(len, col, ...) { # `col` is the column index
  inputs <- character(len)
  for(i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(
      checkboxInput(paste0("checkb_", col, "_", i), label = NULL, ...)
    )
  }
  inputs
}

#This is where the magic for the checkboxes is done
js <- function(dtid, cols, ns = identity) {
  code <- vector("list", length(cols))
  for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
    col <- cols[i]
    code[[i]] <- c(
      sprintf(
        "$('body').on('click', '[id^=checkb_%d_]', function() {",
        col),
      "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
      sprintf(
        "  var i = parseInt(/checkb_%d_(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
        col),
      "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
      sprintf(
        "  var info = [{row: i, col: %d, value: value}];",
        col),
      sprintf(
        "  Shiny.setInputValue('%s', info);",
        ns(sprintf("%s_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo", dtid))
      ),
      "});"
    )
  }
  do.call(c, code)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
    column(
      6,
      numericInput("num_exps", 
                   label = "Enter the number of experimental phases:",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 96,
                   value = 1),
      
      DT::dataTableOutput('phasesTable'),
    ),
    column(
      6,
      verbatimTextOutput("reactiveDF"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ##### Number output for number of conditions #####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_exps })
  
  #Putting each phase and its duration into a data frame
  phases_df <- reactive({data.frame(
    Phases = sapply(1: as.integer(input$num_exps), function(i) {i})
  )})
  
  #calculating the start and end times for each phase, and adding them to phases_df as timings
  timings <- reactive({
    req(phases_df()) %>% 
      mutate(Duration = 0) %>%
      mutate(End = cumsum(Duration)) %>%
      mutate(Start = End - Duration) %>%
      relocate(Start, .before = End)
  })
  
  #This adds the columns into which the checkboxes will be added
  dat1 <- cbind(timings(), 'Linear Regression' = FALSE, 'Habiutation' = FALSE)
  
  #This uses the checkboxColumn function to add check boxes to the declared
  #columns 
  dat2 <- cbind(
    timings(),
    'Linear Regression' = checkboxColumn(nrow(phases_df()), 3),
    'Habiutation' = checkboxColumn(nrow(phases_df()), 4)
  )
  
  Dat <- reactiveVal(dat1)
  
  checkboxesColumns_list <- c(0, 3, 4)
  
  output[["phasesTable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat2, 
      rownames = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(
        target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns_list)
      ),
      options = list(paging = FALSE,
                     ordering = FALSE,
                     scrollx = FALSE,
                     searching = FALSE,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     info = FALSE,
                     columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))),
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(js("phasesTable", checkboxesColumns_list))
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]], { 
    info <- input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]] # this input contains the info of the edit
    Dat(editData(Dat(), info))
  })
  
  output[["reactiveDF"]] <- renderPrint({ 
    Dat()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE** I have updated my code according to Jamie's suggestions and made some other edits as well. I am able to load the app getting new errors, however. In the verbatim, the checkboxes show up as HTML code, and clicking them doesn't change anything in the verbatim. Also, when I try to edit one of the input boxes in the DT, the app crashes and gives me this error:

```
Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Here is the updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

#This adds checkboxes for every row, as many rows are in the dataframe
checkboxColumn <- function(len, col, ...) { # `col` is the column index
  inputs <- character(len)
  for(i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(
      checkboxInput(paste0("checkb_", col, "_", i), label = NULL, ...)
    )
  }
  inputs
}

#This is where the magic for the checkboxes is done
js <- function(dtid, cols, ns = identity) {
  code <- vector("list", length(cols))
  for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
    col <- cols[i]
    code[[i]] <- c(
      sprintf(
        "$('body').on('click', '[id^=checkb_%d_]', function() {",
        col),
      "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
      sprintf(
        "  var i = parseInt(/checkb_%d_(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
        col),
      "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
      sprintf(
        "  var info = [{row: i, col: %d, value: value}];",
        col),
      sprintf(
        "  Shiny.setInputValue('%s', info);",
        ns(sprintf("%s_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo", dtid))
      ),
      "});"
    )
  }
  do.call(c, code)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

 
      numericInput("num_exps", 
                   label = "Enter the number of experimental phases:",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 96,
                   value = 1),
      
      DT::dataTableOutput('phasesTable'),

      br(),
      br(),
      
      verbatimTextOutput("reactiveDF"),

  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ##### Number output for number of conditions #####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_exps })
  
  #Putting each phase and its duration into a data frame
  phases_df <- reactive({
    num_exps <- as.integer(input$num_exps)
    
    data.frame(
    Phases = sapply(1: as.integer(input$num_exps), function(i) {i}),
    'Phaes Comparison Groups' = 0,
    'Phase Name' = "",
    Duration = 0
  )})
  
  #calculating the start and end times for each phase, and adding them to phases_df as timings
  timings <- reactive({
    req(phases_df()) %>% 
      mutate(Duration = 0) %>%
      mutate(End = cumsum(Duration)) %>%
      mutate(Start = End - Duration) %>%
      mutate('Linear Regression' = checkboxColumn(nrow(phases_df()), 6)) %>%
      mutate('Habiutation' = checkboxColumn(nrow(phases_df()), 7)) %>%
      relocate(Start, .before = End) 
  })
  
  checkboxesColumns_list <- c(0, 4, 5)
  
  output$phasesTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      timings(), 
      rownames = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(
        target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns_list)
      ),
      options = list(paging = FALSE,
                     ordering = FALSE,
                     scrollx = FALSE,
                     searching = FALSE,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     info = FALSE,
                     columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))),
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(js("phasesTable", checkboxesColumns_list))
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('phasesTable')
  
  observeEvent(input$phasesTable_cell_edit, { 
    info <- input$phasesTable_cell_edit
    edit_row <- info$row
    edit_col <- info$col   
    edit_value <- info$value
    
    timings()[edit_row, edit_col] <- isolate(coerceValue(edit_value, timings()[edit_row, edit_col]))
    replaceData(proxy, timings(), resetPaging = FALSE) 
  })
  
  output$reactiveDF <- renderPrint({ 
    timings()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing some code. I don't see `editData()` defined anywhere so I can't test properly. You're attempting to save a reactive to a regular variable which isn't possible. e.g. `dat1`/`dat2`.  I would update `timings()` with the code for `dat1` or ignore dat1 completely and use what you have for dat2 in timings. It's not clear to me why you need to store that info in another table. If you add the rest of the code I can test it out.

Comment: I made some changes but am still getting errors, I'll put an update in the question.

Comment: Strange - I got the same error as above the first time I ran it but am unable to recreate it. It appears to be working on my end. I can select/deselect the checkboxes as many times as I want.

Comment: I can select/deselect too. What I'm hoping for is that the verbatim will show `TRUE` or `FALSE` for that cell, like in the question that I gave a link for. Are you able to directly edit the text boxes without the app crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I should have looked at the question you linked, my bad. I now see what you're trying to do. My idea is a bit convoluted but the main issue is, I'm pretty sure you can't set a reactive expression to a reactiveVal. So I convert the `dat1` reactive expression to a dataframe and then set that to a reactiveVal. Then everything else works accordingly. I also updated the col indexes since they were off.

However, it will reset if you add more rows. If you don't want that to happen you'll need to revise how `phases_df` and `timings` are set up.

Below is the updated server code.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ##### Number output for number of conditions #####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_exps })
  
  #Putting each phase and its duration into a data frame
  phases_df <- reactive({data.frame(
    Phases = sapply(1: as.integer(input$num_exps), function(i) {i})
  )})
  
  #calculating the start and end times for each phase, and adding them to phases_df as timings
  timings <- reactive({
    req(phases_df()) %>% 
      mutate(Duration = 0) %>%
      mutate(End = cumsum(Duration)) %>%
      mutate(Start = End - Duration) %>%
      relocate(Start, .before = End)
  })
  
  #This adds the columns into which the checkboxes will be added
  dat1 <- reactive({
    cbind(timings(), 'Linear Regression' = FALSE, 'Habituation' = FALSE)
  })
  
  #This uses the checkboxColumn function to add check boxes to the declared
  #columns 
  dat2 <- reactive({cbind(
    timings(),
    'Linear Regression' = checkboxColumn(nrow(phases_df()), 5),
    'Habituation' = checkboxColumn(nrow(phases_df()), 6)
  )})
  
  Dat = reactiveVal()
  
  # Convert dat1 reactive to data frame and set to a reactiveVal
  observe({
    d = dat1()
    d = as.data.frame(d)
    Dat(d)
  })
  
  checkboxesColumns_list <- c(0, 5, 6)
  
  output[["phasesTable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat2(), 
      rownames = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(
        target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns_list)
      ),
      options = list(paging = FALSE,
                     ordering = FALSE,
                     scrollx = FALSE,
                     searching = FALSE,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     info = FALSE,
                     columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))),
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(js("phasesTable", checkboxesColumns_list))
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]], { 
    info <- input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]] # this input contains the info of the edit
    
    Dat(editData(Dat(), info))
  })
  
  output[["reactiveDF"]] <- renderPrint({ 
    Dat()
  })
  
}
```